# How to use arrow function in forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, callback, arrow-functions

I am studying about arrow function in Javascript.
I used forEach in two ways.
The one without arrow is working, but the one with arrow is not working.

Could you please let me know why?

```
    let ary = [1,2,3,4,5];

    function callback (i) {
        console.log(i);
    }

    // Working
    ary.forEach(callback);

    // Not working
    ary.forEach((i)=>callback);
```

Comment: You're passing to `forEach` a function that _returns_ a function, `callback`. `callback` itself is never called. Please see: [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the "non-working" code, you're passing a function that *returns* a function (`callback`) to forEach. `callback` itself is never called.

This would actually call the function, but it is basically the same as directly passing callback directly to forEach as in your first example:

```
ary.forEach((i) => callback(i));
```

Please see the [documentation for arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 5):

you can use:

```
ary.forEach(i=>callback);
```

But you'd better use arrow function in this way,and there is no need to define `function callback`

```js
let ary = [1,2,3,4,5];

ary.forEach(i=>{
  console.log(i);
});
```

Arrow functions like anonymous functions. That's an array function,and `i` is the param.

```
i=>{
  console.log(i);
}
```

You can learn more from there [Array Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)